# How to separate text into two different columns (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How can I take separate the cities and names based on the capital letters? Some cities only have 2 letters in their abbreviation.

'Kevin DurantBKN'

'Stephen CurryGS'

[photo of the dataframe because it wasnt formatting correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9uYx.png)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression to match two groups: the first one is a string prefix that ends with a lowercase character: `^(.*[a-z])`, the second is a non-empty string suffix that only contains uppercase characters: `([A-Z]+)$`.

In pandas, you could use `extract` as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"String": ["Kevin DurantBKN", "Stephen CurryGS"]})
result = df.String.str.extract(r"^(.*[a-z])([A-Z]+)$")
print(result)
#                0    1
# 0   Kevin Durant  BKN
# 1  Stephen Curry   GS
```